# Opencl not detecting T4 hardware accelerator in colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, opencl, pyopencl

I use a notebook in colab and I started to get the following error message:

```
LogicError: clGetPlatformIDs failed: PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR
```

My code uses PyRQA package, which uses opencl to perform calculations.
It was running without any issue a few weeks ago, but now it keeps showing the error.

The command

```
!clinfo
```

returns the following:

```
Number of platforms                               0
```

It looks like the opencl is not detecting the T4 hardware acceleration, even though it's set in the runtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They somehow removed the OpenCL runtime from drivers in the last update.

But you have sudo permissions, so you can fix the driver installation. After something like

```
!sudo apt update
!sudo apt purge *nvidia* -y
!sudo apt install nvidia-driver-530 -y
```

it works again.