# clGetPlatformIDs(): CL_PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, hashcat

I am getting the below issue for latest hashcat, while trying to run on jupyter notebook on cloud

```
Linux default 4.14.322-246.539.amzn2.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 6 22:22:06 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`hashcat (v6.2.5) starting

clGetPlatformIDs(): CL_PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR

ATTENTION! No OpenCL-compatible, HIP-compatible or CUDA-compatible platform found.

You are probably missing the OpenCL, CUDA or HIP runtime installation.

AMD GPUs on Linux require this driver:
"AMD ROCm" (4.5 or later)
Intel CPUs require this runtime:
"OpenCL Runtime for Intel Core and Intel Xeon Processors" (16.1.1 or later)
NVIDIA GPUs require this runtime and/or driver (both):
"NVIDIA Driver" (440.64 or later)
"CUDA Toolkit" (9.0 or later)
Started: Thu Oct 12 10:53:41 2023
Stopped: Thu Oct 12 10:53:41 2023

Thu Oct 12 11:51:43 2023
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.57.02    Driver Version: 470.57.02    CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            Off  | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   29C    P0    26W /  70W |      0MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

!cd hashcat && hashcat --version && hashcat -I
v6.2.5
hashcat (v6.2.5) starting in backend information mode

clGetPlatformIDs(): CL_PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR

ATTENTION! No OpenCL-compatible, HIP-compatible or CUDA-compatible platform found.

You are probably missing the OpenCL, CUDA or HIP runtime installation.

- AMD GPUs on Linux require this driver:
  "AMD ROCm" (4.5 or later)
- Intel CPUs require this runtime:
  "OpenCL Runtime for Intel Core and Intel Xeon Processors" (16.1.1 or later)
- NVIDIA GPUs require this runtime and/or driver (both):
  "NVIDIA Driver" (440.64 or later)
  "CUDA Toolkit" (9.0 or later)

I have tried a lot to make hashcat work not able to

!hashcat -m 22000 -a 3 -w 2 -d 1 -1 ?l?d?s hash.hc22000 --increment --increment-min 8 --increment-max 12 ?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1

hashcat (v6.2.5) starting

clGetPlatformIDs(): CL_PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR

ATTENTION! No OpenCL-compatible, HIP-compatible or CUDA-compatible platform found.

You are probably missing the OpenCL, CUDA or HIP runtime installation.

- AMD GPUs on Linux require this driver:
  "AMD ROCm" (4.5 or later)
- Intel CPUs require this runtime:
  "OpenCL Runtime for Intel Core and Intel Xeon Processors" (16.1.1 or later)
- NVIDIA GPUs require this runtime and/or driver (both):
  "NVIDIA Driver" (440.64 or later)
  "CUDA Toolkit" (9.0 or later)

Started: Thu Oct 12 10:53:41 2023
Stopped: Thu Oct 12 10:53:41 2023`

Comment: It seems some cloud providers ship their instances with broken driver installations. If you have sudo rights, purge and reinstall GPU drivers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76461740/9178992